# MySQL timestamp select date range

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Not sure really where to start with this one. Can anyone help/point me in the right direction.

I have a timestamp column in MySQL and I want to select a date range for example, all timestamps which are in Oct 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, not mentioned above, it's a unix timestamp, not a mysql timestamp.

Comment: I saw this post and my timestamp works fine the problem I am facing now if calling it with a join its always brings back zero rows returned ...my query is like this SELECT * FROM db.t1, db.t2
WHERE  t2.t1_id = t1.id

AND timestamp >= '2014-06-21' AND timestamp <= '2014-07-20';

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Usually it would be this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM yourtable
 WHERE yourtimetimefield>='2010-10-01'
   AND yourtimetimefield< '2010-11-01'
```

But because you have a unix timestamps, you'll need something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM yourtable
 WHERE yourtimetimefield>=unix_timestamp('2010-10-01')
   AND yourtimetimefield< unix_timestamp('2010-11-01')
```

Comment: @merlinbeard This would actually work totally fine with indexes in that the calculated values are static and can be compared directly with the `yourtimefield` value.  Now if you had `WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(yourtimefield) >= '2010-10-01'` this would disallow indexing as the value for comparison to the date format would need to be calculated for each row.  That being said. I would still suggest using date, datetime, timestamp field types instead of unix timestamps for most use cases.

Comment: @MikeBrant: correct observation. This expression is calculated once and is folded into a constant, and can still be matched against an index on `yourtimefield`. Immediately after merlinbeard's comment i received some downvotes, demonstrating that people often vote without fully understanding what they're voting for. Hey, sounds like politics :)

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick looks like you fixed the sample code after my comment so my comment is not relevant anymore. Thanks for doing that! MikeBrant see the edits to the answer to see my point :-)

Comment: @merlinbeard Yes. The edits made your comment moot. I didn't look at edit history.  But looking at when you commented and when the edit was made, your comment was certainly correct at the time.

Answer (score 39):

A compact, flexible method for timestamps without fractional seconds would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE field_name 
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-10-01') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-10-31 23:59:59')
```

If you are using fractional seconds and a recent version of MySQL then you would be better to take the approach of using the `>=` and `<` operators as per [Wouter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976837/mysql-timestamp-select-date-range/3976946#answer-3976902).

Here is an example of temporal fields defined with fractional second precision (maximum precision in use):

```
mysql> create table time_info (t_time time(6), t_datetime datetime(6), t_timestamp timestamp(6), t_short timestamp null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into time_info set t_time = curtime(6), t_datetime = now(6), t_short = t_datetime;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from time_info;
+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
| 22:05:34.378453 | 2016-01-11 22:05:34.378453 | 2016-01-11 22:05:34.378453 | 2016-01-11 22:05:34 |
+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding converting the column for each comparison. One would hope this was pretty efficient!

Comment: @Jimbo: no, `BETWEEN` is not really a good option here, because it's non-inclusive at both ends. 

You'll have to write something like between '2010-10-01 00:00:00' and  '2010-10-31 23:59:59' to get correct answers, and hope that you don't use milliseconds.

Furthermore, september 31 does not exist, because september only has 30 days. If "30" was meant, then it's not correct because data from september will be returned. In practice MySQL interprets this as october 1 (pretty neat), which would be correct here. I'm not sure why you'd write it as september 31 though.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick not sure exactly what was going on with the values, but fixed. I've added a comment regarding the fsp since this was written before they had effect

Comment: @Cez, ok, that's better, but you'll need another edit :) it now only selects october the 1st only. But really, `BETWEEN` is not handy for this. if you have milliseconds in the timestamp, you'll miss the last second of the month.  You'd have to say: '2010-10-01 23:59:59 999' and hope that MySQL never switches to higher precision timestamps :)

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick 6-digit precision is supported

Answer (score 6):

I can see people giving lots of comments on this question. But I think, simple use of `LIKE` could be easier to get the data from the table.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE COLUMN LIKE '2013-05-11%'
```

Use `LIKE` and post data wild character search. Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col >= '2010-10-01' AND col <= '2010-10-31'
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it's a unix timestamp, not a mysql timestamp (important bit of info to miss out!!)

Comment: I saw this post and my timestamp works fine the problem I am facing now if calling it with a join its always brings back zero rows returned

Comment: So what would happen to records that have a timestamp of `2010-10-31 09:00:00`?

Comment: I think you know the answer, since it's been above this one on the page for 6 years. `WHERE col >= '2010-10-01' AND col < '2010-11-01'`.

Answer (score 4):

This SQL query will extract the data for you. It is easy and fast.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
  WHERE extract( YEAR_MONTH from timestamp)="201010";
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever possible, avoid applying functions to a column in the where clause:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-10-01 00:00:00') 
   AND timestamp <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-11-01 00:00:00');
```

Applying a function to the timestamp column (e.g., FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) = ...) makes indexing much harder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mysql timestamp, something like `2013-09-29 22:27:10` you can do this

```
 select * from table WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)))=9;
```

Convert to unix, then use the unix time functions to extract the month, in this case 9 for september.