# Algorithm or SQL to get closests time ranges available from a table of dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question regarding a good, efficient way, of getting not present dates from a table of dates.

I have the table of dates below. The user will choose a time range to "book" an available place (not exactly a booking application but it's close to that).

I think I will check if the range the user chooses overlaps with the dates present in the table. I will do some kind of select count if column is between startRange and endRange. That's not my main problem... If there is not any overlap, I will insert the new time range.

My question is how can I get the closests time ranges available with the same duration the user chooses.

For example the user chooses startDate = 2013-12-30 11:00:00 and endDate = 2013-12-30 12:00:00.

```
id  startRange          endRange            tstStart   tstEnd
1   2013-12-30 11:00:00 2013-12-30 12:00:00 1388394000  1388397600
2   2013-12-30 14:00:00 2013-12-30 15:00:00 1388408400  1388412000
3   2013-12-30 16:00:00 2013-12-30 17:00:00 1388408400  1388412000
4   2013-12-30 18:00:00 2013-12-30 19:00:00 1388422800  1388426400
5   2013-12-30 22:00:00 2013-12-30 23:00:00 1388437200  1388440800
```

And the desired output would be something like this (we only show the four closests available time ranges):

```
From 2013-12-30 12:00:00 to 2013-12-30 13:00:00
From 2013-12-30 13:00:00 to 2013-12-30 14:00:00
From 2013-12-30 15:00:00 to 2013-12-30 16:00:00
From 2013-12-30 17:00:00 to 2013-12-30 18:00:00
```

Thanks to Kielni I come have a slight Idea of how to aproach the problem. This code gets the closest time ranges to the one the user chooses.

Here's some php:

```php
public function selectCercanos(){
    $rangeStart = 1388394000;
    $rangeEnd = 1388397600;
    $dif = $rangeEnd - $rangeStart;

    $sql = 'select p.startRange, p.endRange, p.tstIni, p.tstEnd from TimeRanges p
        order by abs(p.tstIni-:rangeStart) asc limit 4;';
    $params = array (
            ':rangeStart' => $rangeStart
        );

    return $this->find ( $sql, $params ); //PDO method
}
```

This way I know the gaps duration between the ranges of time ordered

```php
public function getFechasCercanas(){
    $tiemposCercanos = $this->selectCercanos();
    $res = $this->selectCercanos();
    $tmp = null;
    foreach($res as $row){
        if($tmp == null){
            $tmp = $row;
            continue;
        }
        $dt1 = new DateTime($tmp['endRange']);
        $dt2 = new DateTime($row['startRange']);
        $interval = $dt1->diff($dt2);
         $interval->format('%H horas')."\n";
        echo "from: ".$tmp['endRange']. " to: ".$row['startRange']. " lapse: ".
             $interval->format('%y years %m months %d days %H hours')."\n";

        $tmp = $row;
    } 
}
```

The code above gets me what I want. I would like to know if is there any algorithm or good query to find this same results more efficiently?

I hope the question is a little clearer than before and I understand my problem a little better.

Comment: Have you tried anything, efficiently or not?  The first step to getting code to perform well is to get code that works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I didn't try anything because I don't have a clue of how to aproach the problem. Thanks to the post below I have now an Idea of how to do it.

Comment: Did you try searching around for people who've asked the problem before? Say, "mysql how to select range of dates"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL timestamp select date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976837/mysql-timestamp-select-date-range)

Comment: Thanks r3mus, I did. I am looking for a way to find the gaps in the database, not ranges in the database.

Comment: Check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6810dc/16), it requires additional sequence table (or some magic to generate it on the fly), but solves the problem with a single query.

Comment: I have edited a little bit the question. I hope it is decent enough now. If not, please, explain what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select rows where the difference between the end time and the start time matches your interval, and order by the difference between your desired start time and the row's start time.

For example:

```
select id, startRange, endRange from table_name_here 
where (tstEnd-tstStart)=(1388397600-1388394000) 
order by abs(1388394000-tstStart) asc limit 4;
```

In English:
Select rows where the interval (tstEnd-tstStart) equals your requested interval and order by the absolute value of the difference between your requested start time and the row's start time, smallest difference first and maximum four rows.

Notes:

it's easier to work with integers instead of dates; I see you've stored an integer timestamp in your table already.  Convert your request start/end to integers as well.  For this example, requested start=1388394000 and requested end=1388397600

For ease of explanation, I have `(tstEnd-tstStart)=(1388397600-1388394000)`, but for efficiency you should calculate your requested interval `(1388397600-1388394000)` once in your code instead of for each row.

Make sure you use placeholders instead of pasting the values directly into a query string.

Comment: THanks Kielni. I updated the post.
I don't think I need the where clause since I don't want to get the ranges with the same duration. I want to know the gaps between them.