# sqlQuery where timestamp is a specific date

Tags: mysql, database, heidisql

Hy guys I have this table:
VisitedCity

| id | timestamp | name | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 10:02:23 | Mark | LA |
| 2 | 2022-01-15 08:45:01 | Phil | NY |
| 3 | 2022-02-05 11:09:45 | John | MI |

My query :

```
SELECT * FROM VisitedCity
WHERE timestamp = '2022-02-02'
```

But it doesn't return any rows.
How Could I do it?

Comment: use WHERE timestamp LIKE '2022-02-02%'

Comment: Review date functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: @Pawan.Java thanks, it works

Comment: @Pawan.Java This can do for a quick and dirty query, but using string manipulation functions to deal with dates almost never pays off in the long term. Code becomes harder to maintain, performance suffers and it's easy for bugs to slip in.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I know but given the problem statement, he was looking for something quick itself.

Comment: @gianluca23 your question is a copy of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976837/mysql-timestamp-select-date-range/3976902
Make good use ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `=` if you don't want an exact match. You need to query for an interval:

```
SELECT *
FROM VisitedCity
WHERE timestamp >= '2022-02-02 00:00:00' AND timestamp < '2022-02-03 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks, I have modified only the last part in `timestamp < DATE_ADD( '2022-02-02 ', INTERVAL 1 DAY) `